# In markdown-mode cursor goes to beginning of line when I type certain characters

Tags: markdown, markdown-mode

In markdown-mode the cursor goes to the beginning of a line whenever I type any of `(),[]{};:`, this happens in both GUI and command-line emacs, this only happens in markdown-mode.

How do I stop this from happening?

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.1

Comment: I assume there is a problem with your init file. Try bisecting it to find the culprit. `markdown-mode` doesn't ship with Emacs, so you'll have to keep it somehow loaded during your testing. You can try commenting out parts of your init file until you find the offending customization.

Comment: Start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, to test without your init file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a line in my init file that was loading funda-haxe-mode

Comment: Please consider deleting the question and answer, if you think they won't help others. Thx.